# Converse to matrix similarity

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$, with representation $[T]_{\mathscr{B}}$ in the basis $\mathscr{B}$ and representation $[T]_{\mathscr{B}'}$ in the basis $\mathscr{B}'$. If we have $[T]_{\mathscr{B}'} = P^{-1} [T]_{\mathscr{B}}P$, must we have $[v]_{\mathscr{B}'} = P[v]_{\mathscr{B}}$?

I took a stab at answering this, letting $Q$ be the change-of-basis matrix such that $[v]_{\mathscr{B}'} = Q[v]_{\mathscr{B}}$, and got to a pretty useless equation, $P^{-1} [T]_{\mathscr{B}'}P = Q^{-1}[T]_{\mathscr{B}'}Q$. (My plan was to show $P = Q$.)

I don't really have the intuition yet to know whether this question is a howler, or spot-on. It doesn't seem to be obviously true.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example to your second point: Assume that $[T]_{\mathscr{B}'}=I$, then $P^{-1} [T]_{\mathscr{B}'}P = Q^{-1}[T]_{\mathscr{B}'}Q$ does not lead us to $P=Q$.

As for the whole problem I think you need $P^{-1} [T]_{\mathscr{B}}P = Q^{-1}[T]_{\mathscr{B}}Q \Rightarrow P=Q$, which is also false by replacing $\mathscr{B}'$ with $\mathscr{B}$ in the counterexample.